# .Net Options for in-memory queues similar to AWS SQS

Tags: .net, queue, message-queue, amazon-sqs

To help increase performance/reduce latency in my application I am attempting to replace my SQS Queues with in memory ones and I am looking for options.

A basic idea of my queue setup is as follows:

1. Command Handlers - Listen for messages sent to CommandHandlers queue, publishes messages to Events Queue
2. Builders - Listen for messages sent to Events Queue

I use a service bus to hook the queues up and decide where to handle them.

I have attempted to try out NetMq but I am struggling with the patterns I should be using.  From my point of view all I am trying to do is create a queue, send a message to it, and receive the message.

Are there any examples of how I can do this/anything I can check out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think NetMQ is good option, I build that can kind of a bus with NetMQ few times.

Did you try to read the zeromq guide? 
Also included is a link on how to build some of the patterns.

[1] http://zguide.zeromq.org/
[2] https://github.com/somdoron/NetMQ.High